# API development, FastAPI / SQLAlchemy , relationship() question

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I am working on completing an API development course ([here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0sOvCWFmrtA&ab_channel=freeCodeCamp.org)). I am currently at 8:33:37 Sqlalchemy Relationships and have run into an issue.

In this course we have two tables; "posts" and "users". Here is the code from my models.py file:

```
from .database import Base
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, Boolean, TIMESTAMP, text, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship


class Post(Base):
    __tablename__ = "posts"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    owner_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("users.id", ondelete="CASCADE"), nullable=False,)
    title = Column(String, nullable=False)
    content = Column(String, nullable=False)
    published = Column(Boolean, server_default="TRUE", nullable=False)
    created_at = Column(TIMESTAMP(timezone=True), nullable=False, server_default=text('now()'))

    # This will return an owner property based on the relationship with "User" class, fetches data for us, do not need to do manually
    owner = relationship("User")


class User(Base): 
    __tablename__ = "users"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    email = Column(String, nullable=False, unique=True)
    password = Column(String, nullable=False)
    created_at = Column(TIMESTAMP(timezone=True), nullable=False, server_default=text('now()'))
```

I am trying to run a path operation that returns all the posts in the table and also provides the user information who created the post. This is supposed to be possible by using the relationship() function at the end of the "posts" table. But when I run the path operation to retireve all posts. I do not recieve any user information.

This is my path operation:

```
## ORM GET query
# must use List[] from typing library because FastAPI trys to up all posts into a single dict
@router.get("/", response_model=List[schemas.PostResponse])
def get_posts(db: Session = Depends(get_db), current_user: int = Depends(oauth2.get_current_user)):
    posts = db.query(models.Post).all()
    return posts
```

And this is my schema for the response:

```
# response when account is created
class UserOut(BaseModel):
    id: int
    email: EmailStr
    created_at: datetime

    # Pydantic's orm_mode will tell the Pydantic model to read the data even if its not a dict, but and ORM model (or any other arbitary object with attributes)
    class Config:
        orm_mode = True

# class for the FastAPI response, limits what is sent in resposne, schema, this is used within the decorator under main.py
class PostResponse(PostBase):
    # other attributes inherited from class PostBase 
    id: int
    owner_id: int
    created_at: datetime
    # New property type: owner, Returns a pydantic model type: UserOut 
    owner = UserOut
```

The "PostResponse" schema contains the property type owner, which is supposed to grab the Users "id", "email", and "created_at" information using the relationship() function when the path operation is called. Currently I am only recieving information about the post and not any information about the user who created the post. I have rewatched the video multiple times but can't seem to find where my code is any different from the tutorial. I do not know if there is an error in my code or if SQLAlchemy has changed since this tutorial was released. I am new to API development, I apologise for using any incorrect terminology. Thank you,

I currently recieve a JSON response that looks like:

```
[
    {
        "title": "testtest",
        "content": "testtest",
        "published": true,
        "id": 1,
        "owner_id": 8,
        "created_at": "2023-07-12T15:06:31.812181-04:00"
    }
]
```

I want to recieve a JSON response that looks like:

```
[
    {
        "title": "testtest",
        "content": "testtest",
        "published": true,
        "id": 1,
        "owner_id": 8,
        "created_at": "2023-07-12T15:06:31.812181-04:00"
        "owner": {
            "id": 23,
            "email": "123@gamil.com",
            "created_at": some date_time type    
    }
]
```

Comment: You have `owner = UserOut` in your `PostResponse` model, it should be `owner: UserOut`

Comment: @M.O. wow, thank you very much. It works now. What a careless mistake. Thank you for your help.